# Command maven run but with errors

Tags: maven

I did the following tutorial:
                  http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html 
and when I do the following step: mvn package, I get the error shown bellow

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile           (default-compile) on project idArtefactoMyAplicacion: Fatal error compiling: directory not    found: /home/user/Escritorio/primeraAppMaven/idArtefactoMyAplicacion/target/classes -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project idArtefactoMyAplicacion: Fatal error compiling
```

I don't have the directory specified, but I do every step describe in the guide, so I don't know what is wrong.

somebody can help please?

Comment: What tutorial? Care to include some config/code?

Comment: kindly share your folder structure and pom.xml

Comment: sorry, I stick the link now.

Comment: Strange. Maven is supposed to create the directory structure. What happens if you create the directory with `mkdir`?